# Is it possible to find the exact positions of a certain item in a nested loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to find all the positions of `HSE` in the nested loop below?

```
map1 = [ ['   ', '   ', '   ', '   '],\
         ['   ', '   ', 'SHP', '   '],\
         ['   ', 'HSE', 'HSE', 'FAC'],\
         ['   ', 'BCH', '   ', 'HSE'] ]
```

I am only aware of using index, but it returns the first value only. Below is my codes:

```
HSE_list = []

for x in map1:
    if 'HSE' in x:
         y = (map1.index(x), x.index('HSE'))
         HSE_list.append(y)
print(HSE_list)
```

It returns the first item in every list which comes in contact with, so no matter how many `HSE` I have in the nested loop, it will still only show the first `HSE` that it sees in `map[0]`,`map[1]`,`map[2]`,`map[3]`. My print will return as: `[(2, 1), (3, 3)]` when I run the program.

is there any way that I can make it show all the positions of the house in my nested list, `[(2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a list comprehension with `enumerate`:

```
print([(idx, i) for idx, sublist in enumerate(map1) for i, v in enumerate(sublist) if v == 'HSE'])
```

Output:

```
[(2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```